# Select data from n tables using same id

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have 10 tables with more or less same columns, like, i am putting all fruits info in one table, chocolate info in one table an so on. 
Every table has 3 common columns - **ITEM_ID**, **ITEM_NAME**, **USER_ID**.

**USER_ID** is the id of user who saved the data.

Now suppose i am the user and i have inserted some data in all the tables.
Now i want to get the ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME from all the tables which are **entered by me** that means the rows from all the tables which have my USER_ID.

Comment: And see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` query results:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME FROM table1 WHERE USER_ID = value
UNION
SELECT ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME FROM table2 WHERE USER_ID = value
UNION
SELECT ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME FROM table3 WHERE USER_ID = value
// and etc
```

Comment: This assumes (not entirely unreasonably) that it will somehow be obvious which item belongs to which table

Comment: Thanks, but i have denormalized my tables, i have created an extra table which will hold all the data that will be needed to generate report.